# Integration testing using spock

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

In my application there is `AddressBookController` which has an `editContact` action as shown below:

```
def editContact(){
    AddressBook addressBook=AddressBook.findById(params.addressBookId)
    render view: 'addContact', model: [addressBook:addressBook]
}
```

Now I am trying to test for view and model as:

```
class AddressBookControllerSpec extends IntegrationSpec{

AddressBookController addressBookController = new AddressBookController()

void setup() {

}

def "editContact action renders view with addressBook details"() {
    when:
    addressBookController.editContact()
    then:
    addressBookController.modelAndView.model.addressBook
}

void cleaup() {
    // Tear down logic here
 }
}
```

But my testcase gets failed with the stacktrace as:

Running 2 spock tests... 1 of 2

```
| Failure:  editContact action renders view with addressBook details(cvsurgeon.AddressBookControllerSpec)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'model' on null object
    at cvsurgeon.AddressBookControllerSpec.setup(AddressBookControllerSpec.groovy:15)
| Completed 2 spock tests, 1 failed in 660ms
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in ....
```

What could be the problem.

Comment: Are you able to render the view with the model data when you hit the action in browser after a `run-app`?

Comment: Yep, My edit view is rendering with model corrrectly.

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.0 ,I have tested for new app still this gives the same result.I think that modelAndView is not gets instantiated by the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..,.

```
AddressBookController controller = new AddressBookController()

def "editContact action renders view with addressBook details"() {
  when:
    controller.params.addressBookId = 1   //valid id 
    controller.editContact()
  then:
    assert controller.modelAndView.model.addressBook
    assert controller.modelAndView.modelMap.addressBook
    assert controller.modelAndView.viewName == "/addressBook/addContact"
}
```